# JS OR Jquery to Add Link to List items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how would I add a link to each list item?

basically I have a list and i want to use js or jquery to added in href for my search page.

```
<aside class="listlinks">
        <ul>
            <li>CRM</li>
            <li>CTI</li>
            <li>Call Center</li>
            <li>Data warehouse</li>
            <li>Documentum D2</li>
            <li>MDM</li>
            <li>SharePoint</li>
        </ul>
    </aside>

$('.listlinks').each(function(){
    $(this).wrapInner('<a href="\search.php?' + $(this).html() + '" />');
});
```

Comment: Update: Make sure to encode the text in the url. Just remembered that.(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example would work as long as you updated the jQuery selector to match the list items instead of the parent list, e.g. replace `.listlinks` with `.listlinks ul li`. You should also make sure you properly encode the text in the `href` portion with `encodeURI` or `encodeURIComponent`.

You don't really need jQuery for this and using pure Javascript and manually concatenating would save you 3-4 function calls per list item.

```
$('.listlinks ul li').each(function(){
    this.innerHTML = '<a href="\search.php?' + encodeURIComponent(this.innerHTML) + '">' + this.innerHTML + '</a>';
});
```

You can shorten this even more by sacrificing one function call per list item and using `String.prototype.link`. The `link` method automatically wraps string objects with a hyperlink to the supplied URL.

```
$('.listlinks ul li').each(function(){
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.link('\search.php?' + encodeURIComponent(this.innerHTML));
});
```

Comment: @Lucas Yeah, definitely! I Was reading through a guide on saving bytes for code golf where it was mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.listlinks ul li').each(function(){
    $(this).append('<a href="\search.php?' + $(this).html() + '" />');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$('.listlinks ul li').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).html();
    $(this).html('<a href="\search.php?' +  encodeURIComponent(text) + '">' + text +  '</a>');
});
```

Update:
Make sure to encode the text in the url. Just remembered that

Comment: Woops, I forgot to encode the URL in mine, thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

@ Rayen Kamta try this:

```
$.each($('.listlinks li'),function(k,v){
    $(v).wrap('<a href="\search.php?' + $(v).html() + '" />');
});
```